# Facebook app invite : how to redirect to a website if invited user comes from web browser?

Tags: android, facebook

I got an app_invite facebook that is woraking on android, I specify the package name in the applink and it works just fine  :

```
< meta property="al:android:package" content="com.packagename"/>
```

With this, if I invite from an android, the invited user can see the invite on an android. 
But what if the user is using a web browser ? I want the app invite to show as well and lead the a web page of my app (the playstore page for example : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.packagename).
What am I suppose to set in my applink to have this behavior ?

This doesn't work :

```
< meta property="al:web:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.packagename" />
< meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="true"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites) is a **mobile-only** product.

Also see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/bestpractices#usage_in_games

> You may be aware of another invites product specifically tailored to
>   the mechanics of games, [Game
>   Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/). Game
>   Requests have proven to be successful for game developers who have a
>   presence on the web and mobile. If you are a mobile-only game
>   developer we encourage you try out App Invites and determine the best
>   solution for each of your games.